# Solving identifierForVendor/uniqueIdentifier for apps targeted at pre-iOS6

Tags: ios5, ios6, ios7

We have an app targeting iOS 5 that uses UIDevice.uniqueIdentifier to get an ID for the device.

On iOS 6 and later we're replacing this with UIDevice.identifierForVendor.

When we submitted however, the app got rejected for using UIDevice.uniqueIdentifier - which we need on iOS 5 since it doesn't support UIDevice.identifierForVendor.

Does this simply mean we can no longer support iOS 5 - since we can no longer submit an app that has a way to get a device ID?